# FullPage.js and Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, fullpage.js

I have created a jsFiddle creating a basic example.

http://jsfiddle.net/7PwsS/532/

It works great on jsFiddle, put it in my Meteor app and when I click the link it doesn't work, if I scroll it does.

Here is my meteor code for layout.html:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> yield}}   
</template>


<template name="index">
<div id="fullpage">
 <div id="section0" class="section" data-anchor="firstPage">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstPage">
          <a href="#secondPage">First slide</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div id="section1" class="section" data-anchor="secondPage">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
          <h1>fullPage.js</h1>
            <ul id="menu">
              <li data-menuanchor="firstPage">
                <a href="#firstPage">First slide</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Routes.js file in Lib folder

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('index', {
    path: '/'
  });
});
```

Script.js file in Server Folder

```
Template.index.rendered = function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage'],
        menu: '#menu'
    });
};
```

It is weird, I am guessing something to do with iron-router?

Cheers

J

Comment: I guess `iron-router` is catching your links, so if `fullpage` plugin rellies on `click` events it won't work out of the box with `iron-router`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make it work with iron-router?

Answer (score 1):

you should use the **moveTo()** fullPage.Js function, to keep your iron setting simple ...
[FullPage doc over here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movetosection-slide)

and handle the page scrolling with a Meteor Template events handler like this :

```js
Template._header.events({
    "click .scroll-link": function(evt, tpl){
      var sNum = $(evt.currentTarget).data().section;
      //console.log('section number is: '+ sNum);
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(sNum, 0);
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="_header">
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="brand-logo " href="{{pathFor home}}">HOME</a>
          <ul id="menu" class="right">
            <li> <a class="scroll-link" data-section="1">first</a></li>
            <li> <a class="scroll-link" data-section="2">second</a></li>
            <li> <a class="scroll-link" data-section="3">third</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

This way you will get the best of the two worlds...

Answer (score 0):

You can decide which links should be captured by `iron-router` by providing a custom `linkSelector` like this:

```
Router.configure({
   linkSelector: /* selector for iron-router-links */
});
```